# async/await seems to hang inside web method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sendgrid-api-v3

In C# I have a web service with an operation result defined as below:

```
OperationResult<createAccountResponse> CreateAccount(string token, createAccountServiceModel model);
```

Inside that method I call another method with a signature indicating it is async, like so:

```
var sendEmailInvite = this.SendExhibitorInviteEmailAsync(new ExhibitorInviteEmailPartialRequest()
{
    CompanyId = company.CompanyID,
    EventId = event.EventID
});
```

And inside SendExhibitorInviteEmailAsync I await a method which is also marked as async. Here is that method (snipped for brevity)

```
public async Task<ExhibitorInviteEmailResponse> SendExhibitorInviteEmailAsync(ExhibitorInviteEmailResolvedRequest request)
{
    ExhibitorInviteEmailResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        response = new ExhibitorInviteEmailResponse();
        var apiKey = "snip";
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("noreply@domain.com", "Display name"));
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(request.EmailAddress, request.AccountOwnerFirstName));
        msg.SetTemplateId("snipped");
\
        msg.SetTemplateData(dynamicTemplateData);
        await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = new ExhibitorInviteEmailResponse
        {
            Success = false,
            Error = true,
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        };
    }
    return response;
}
```

If the email is meant to be sent (flag field in the json) then I start working on the email.If no email is meant to be sent, the whole method takes about a second which was what it was before.

The issue I am having is when I run this method from Postman or from C# generated by Postman, it seems the async code for sending the email causes the duration of the request to be 30+ seconds - so it seems like something is not waiting for the email to send? When I run this via a browser it works in 1-2 seconds with no delay.

What is the recommended flow when using Postman and async? Do all internal method's parents have to await as well?

Comment: You need to include more code, what do you do with `sendEmailInvite` after you get it back? I bet you have a `sendEmailInvite.Result` somewhere.

Comment: Its very unlikely there is a bug with the async and await pattern. There is nothing inherently wrong with your code, so all evidence points to what you are doing elsewhere or  how you are measuring and drawing your assumptions

Comment: The call to the async/await function is nestled inside a database transaction, so I think that might be why the delay comes about, as it has to try and resume that?